# Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

**I am using Laravel 4. I am not sure why I am getting this error when everything seems to be correct. Also, the product is not updating to the database.**

***Can't write image data to path (E:\wamp\www/E:\wamp\www/img/products/1405482517.jpg)***

ProductsController

```
public function postCreate()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Products::$rules);

    if($validator->passes())
    {
        $products = new Products();
        $products->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
        $products->title = Input::get('title');
        $products->description = Input::get('descroption');
        $products->price = Input::get('price');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save(public_path($path));

        $products->image = 'img/products/'.$filename;
        $products->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/products')
            ->with('message', 'Products added success');

    }else

    return Redirect::to('admin/products')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your products directory doesn't have write permissions. Not sure if you pasted it wrong, but your else statement is missing the {} parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the right permission to your `public/img/products` folder, e.g. `chmod 775 public/image/products` in your terminal.

Another thing is, you are doing public_path() twice, which results in your code trying to save to:

```
E:\wamp\www/E:\wamp\www/img/products/1405482517.jpg
```

instead of

```
E:\wamp\www/img/products/1405482517.jpg
```

Hence the error message: "Can't write image data to path (***E:\wamp\www/E:\wamp\www***/img/products/1405482517.jpg)"

To fix it, this is the section of the code that is causing the problem:

```
$path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save(public_path($path));
```

You'll have to try remove one of the two `public_path()` above.

And of course, you do not see your product in the database because the exception is thrown before `$products->save();` can be executed.

Comment: i deleted public_path in save method
but new Erorr message => (Can't write image data to path (E:\wamp\www/img/products/1405519709.jpg)

my project path is : E:\wamp\www\ecom 

ecom folder not found in path .this is problem

Comment: Sounds like you have customized your laravel folder structure? The easiest to fix is of course just change `img/products/` to `ecom/img/products`. Letting us know how you've structured your folders would help for a better solution I suppose.